# Item with lookup to Brand query

Tags: lookup, lookup-field

I have object Item with lookup field to Brand and i want to get Brand name through Item. I think that i need to use __r object, but how? There are my query, but its not right. I have some trouble with relationships.

```
SELECT Id, Name, (Select Name from Items__r) from Item__c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To go *up* to a parent record, use `Parent__r.Name`; to go *down* to children records, use `(SELECT Name FROM Child__r)`.

As such, I believe you're looking for:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Brand__r.Name from Item__c
```

The inverse of this query would be:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT Name FROM Items__r) FROM Brand__c
```

Comment: thanks, i thought i must use plural label.

Comment: @Hifok The child relationship name is plural by default, but you can specify whatever name you want in the Object Manager.